# Tesseract CPU Usage 100%

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to read business card using Tesseract but when I do that Phone's CPU usage goes to 100%. How to fix that ? Before tesseract is called, CPU usage is ~1%.
Also I'm getting poor result in reading. How to increase that accuracy?

```
    let tesseract:G8Tesseract = G8Tesseract(language:"eng");
    tesseract.delegate = self;
    tesseract.image = image

    tesseract.recognize();

    NSLog("%@", tesseract.recognizedText);
    if let recognizedText = tesseract.recognizedText{
        print(recognizedText)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> [...] using Tesseract but when I do that Phone's CPU usage goes to 100%.

OCR is expected to be a CPU intensive task.

> How to fix that?

You can try to reduce the number of pixels fed to Tesseract. That means reducing the image's resolution or use a tighter crop.

> Also I'm getting poor result in reading.

One possibility would be to use image preprocessing to enhance detection quality. Another option is to use a different OCR library. Most are commercial but offer increased quality in some situations.